# Passing a prototype method to a Promise's then method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a promisified method I called readFilePromise, that resolves to a Buffer object from fs' readFile method.  When I execute the following line

```
return readFilePromise(filePath).then(Buffer.prototype.toString.call);
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

However, when I execute the block:

```
return readFilePromise(filePath).then((data) => {
    return Buffer.prototype.toString.call(data);
});
```

I get no error and the code executes fine.

In my mind they should be the same.  Am I missing something obvious?

node v6.10.1

Comment: Do you really want to use `call` instead of doing `data.toString()`?

Comment: No, i wanted to use the first example.   the second was for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Buffer.prototype.toString.call` is just `Function.prototype.call` which calls `this` using first object as a context. In your first example `this` inside `call` call will be `undefined`.

You need to bind `call` to `Buffer.prototype.toString` like this `Buffer.prototype.toString.call.bind(Buffer.prototype.toString)`.

```
return readFilePromise(filePath)
   .then(Buffer.prototype.toString.call.bind(Buffer.prototype.toString))
```